# Thymeleaf: Getting Property or field cannot be found on null. Iteration of list inside a list

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to iterate a list of transactions (inside AllTransaction object) in my html using thymeleaf. I debugged and object is getting populated properly while adding to model. But gives this exception when trying to iterate . Need to iterate transactions list in AllTransactions which is another list.

AllTransactions.java

```
public class AllTransactions {

    public String tickerName;

    public List<Transactions> transactions;

    public String getTickerName() {
        return tickerName;
    }

    public void setTickerName(String tickerName) {
        this.tickerName = tickerName;
    }

    public List<Transactions> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transactions> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }
}
```

html code

```
<div th:each="itemx : ${alltxs2}">
  <div th:each="tx : ${itemx.transactions}"> 
    <div th:text="${tx.Broker}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
  List<AllTransactions> allTransactions= new ArrayList<AllTransactions>();
            AllTransactions alltraTransactions= new AllTransactions();
            for(String ticker: tickers) {
                transactions = m.makeCall(ticker);
                 alltraTransactions.setTransactions(transactions);
                 alltraTransactions.setTickerName(ticker);
                 allTransactions.add(alltraTransactions);
            }

            model.addAttribute("alltxs2",allTransactions);
```

StackTrace

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "tx.Broker" (template: "index2" - line 42, col 59)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at 
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'Broker' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213) ~[spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406) ~[spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90) ~[spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109) ~[spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:328) ~[spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you add the stack trace also?

Comment: @soorapadam Added

Comment: So in the Transactions object did you define variable name `Broker` or `broker`?

Comment: @soorapadman  public String Broker;

Comment: ok just want to make sure this error used to come when you access wrong property name . As per the java convention pls don't define name like that . Im doubt your transaction object might have problem may be getter and setter . if possible share that too.\

Comment: @soorpadam this object is already existing object  public String getBroker() {
  return Broker;
 }
 public void setBroker(String broker) {
  Broker = broker;
 }

Comment: @soorapadman i changed it to broker and accordingly modified getter n setter in code and its same as above mentioned iisue

Comment: this is obvious error . if nothing work we have to check which object `broker ` coming null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189834/discussion-between-shivi-sharma-and-soorapadman).

Answer (score 1):

Solution:-
Here is the solution i used to solve the problem

```
<div th:each="itemx : ${alltxs}"> 
       <th:block th:each="tx : ${itemx}"> 
       <th:block th:each="x: ${tx.transactions}">
       <div th:text="${x.broker}"></div>
       </th:block>
      </th:block>
   </th:div>
```