# Spring Boot / Thymeleaf - loop within a loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an application with two entities that have a bidirectional one to many relationship. Owners and Bicycles.

So getting the owners via curl will give

```
[
    {"id":1,
    "userName":"user1",
    "bicycles":
        [
            {
                "id":1,
                "make":"dawes",
                "model":"civic",
                "owner":1
            }
        ]
    },
    {"id":2,
    "userName":"user2",
    "bicycles":
        [
            {
                "id":2,
                "make":"whyte",
                "model":"montpellier",
                "owner":2
            }
            ,{
                "id":4,
                "make":"dahon",
                "model":"tern A7",
                "owner":2
            }
        ]
    } ]
```

which is fine.

If I create a template which loops in a table,

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="owner : ${owners}">
      <td th:text="${owner.userName}"></td>
      <td th:text="${owner.bicycles[0].make}"
          th:if="${#lists.size(owner.bicycles)} > 0">"</td>
      <td th:text="${owner.bicycles[0].model}"
          th:if="${#lists.size(owner.bicycles)} > 0"></td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
```

then I get the expected result in the browser. I realise the above is awful code but I am just interested in getting thymeleaf to work at the moment.

But if I do the following code

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="owner : ${owners}">
      <td th:text="${owner.userName}"></td>
      <tr th:each="bike : ${owner.bicycles}">
          <td th:text="${bike.make}"></td>
          <td th:text="${bike.model}"></td>  
      </tr>  
    </tr>
  </table>
```

then I get the following console error

> nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression: "owner.bicycles" (template:
>   "nutsthymeleaf" - line 23, col 15)] with root cause
>
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:
>   Property or field 'bicycles' cannot be found on null

What I find confusing is that owner.bicycle[index] works. It shows make and model. Yet owner.bicycles appears to be a null field according to the error.

So obviously I am doing something wrong ….

Comment: From my point of view also the first solution should give you a `Property or field 'bicycles' cannot be found on null` exception. Just tried it with an example. Check if bicycles is really not null.

Comment: Is that the actual code?  The error message is not saying that `bicycles` doesn't exist, but rather that `${owner}` is null, and so it can't get a property of a null object.  Are you sure that you didn't accidentally close the loop and `${owner}` is out of scope?

Comment: @Metroids - I can't see how it goes out of scope. Owner is supposed to be valid to all child tags. Hopefully that includes another each. 
This has proved valid in other stackoverflow questions.
I accept that it is saying owner is null.
Is <tr> within a <tr> legal?

Comment: Well, typically you'd do that with a `<th:block>` rather than nested `<tr>s`, but it should work either way. I'm just saying that the error you are getting can't be explained by the code you have (as far as i can tell).

Comment: just before you do return can yo debug to see how the owners attribute that you add on model looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this

[Thymeleaf: Getting Property or field cannot be found on null. Iteration of list inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095198/thymeleaf-getting-property-or-field-cannot-be-found-on-null-iteration-of-list)

and that has stopped SpelException.

Having played around with it, it does not need 3 levels but just two. The problem arises if a th:each is nested within a th:each. The second th:each has to be in a th:block (or possibly div).

Answer (score 0):

Try `if` for check `bicycles` is *null* or not

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="owner : ${owners}">
      <td th:text="${owner.userName}"></td>
      <tr th:if={owner.bicycles != null} th:each="bike : ${owner.bicycles}">
          <td th:text="${bike.make}"></td>
          <td th:text="${bike.model}"></td>  
      </tr>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Same error but slightly different.

Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "owner.bicycles" (template: "nutsthymeleaf" - line 23, col 49)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: 
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "owner.bicycles" 
(template: "nutsthymeleaf" - line 23, col 49)

And the code is 
<tr th:if="${owner.bicycles} != null" th:each="bike : ${owner.bicycles}">

So, it seems to accept owner.bicycles in the if but not in the each. And, of course, it accepts owner.bicycles[index].field in earlier code and when finding the length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to generate invalid HTML by nesting table row `<tr>` elements.

To generate the HTML you want, you should use the [syntethic `th:block` tag](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag) , which allows you to generate the cells for each bike.

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="owner : ${owners}">
      <td th:text="${owner.userName}"></td>
      <th:block th:each="bike : ${owner.bicycles}">
          <td th:text="${bike.make}"></td>
          <td th:text="${bike.model}"></td>  
      </th:block>  
    </tr>
  </table>
```