# Thymeleaf not finding variable in each

Tags: java, thymeleaf

First time using Thymeleaf and I'm having a bit of trouble. I want to display a table with customers and their orderProducts. My class looks like this,

```java
class GroupOrderCustomer {
    private String customerName;
    private double totalPrice;
    private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts;
}
```

When inspecting my list of `groupOrderCustomers` we can see this,
[image]

I also add `groupOrderCustomers` to the context of my mail,

```java
Context context = new Context(locale);
context.setVariable("groupOrderCustomers", groupOrderCustomers);

final String groupOrderConfirmationTemplate = "html/groupOrderConfirmation";
String htmlContent = emailTemplateEngine.process(groupOrderConfirmationTemplate, context);
helper.setText(htmlContent, true);
```

When trying to send the email I get this in my console,

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "groupOrderCustomer.orderProducts"
EL1007E: Property or field 'orderProducts' cannot be found on null
```

This is my email,

```html
<table th:each="groupOrderCustomer : ${groupOrderCustomers}">
  <tr>
    <td th:text="${groupOrderCustomer.customerName}" align="left">
      Martin
    </td>
    <td th:text="${groupOrderCustomer.totalPrice}" align="right">
      100 kr
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td>
    <table th:each="orderProduct : ${groupOrderCustomer.orderProducts}">
      <tr>
        <td th:text="${orderProduct.quantity} + 'st ' + ${orderProduct.name}" align="left">
          1st Kombo
        </td>
        <td th:text="${orderProduct.totalPrice}" align="right">
          100 kr
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</table>
```

When I wrote, `th:each="orderProduct : ${groupOrderCustomer.orderProducts}"`, I expected Thymeleaf to pick-up `groupOrderCustomer` from the first `th:each`.

When commenting out the second `th:each` the email gets sent.

I appreciate all the help I can get for this. Thank you!

Comment: Would using `<th:block>` fix it (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095198/thymeleaf-getting-property-or-field-cannot-be-found-on-null-iteration-of-list)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the table structure. After the first closing `</tr>` tag, I have an `<td>`, but I should actually have another `<tr>`.

Broken:

```html
<table th:each="groupOrderCustomer : ${groupOrderCustomers}">
  <tr>
    <td th:text="${groupOrderCustomer.customerName}" align="left">
      Martin
    </td>
    <td th:text="${groupOrderCustomer.totalPrice}" align="right">
      100 kr
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td>
    <table th:each="orderProduct : ${groupOrderCustomer.orderProducts}">
      <tr>
        <td th:text="${orderProduct.quantity} + 'st ' + ${orderProduct.name}" align="left">
          1st Kombo
        </td>
        <td th:text="${orderProduct.totalPrice}" align="right">
          100 kr
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</table>
```

Working:

```html
<table th:each="groupOrderCustomer : ${groupOrderCustomers}">
  <tr>
    <td th:text="${groupOrderCustomer.customerName}" align="left">
      Martin
    </td>
    <td th:text="${groupOrderCustomer.totalPrice}" align="right">
      100 kr
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <!--- Missing --->
    <td>
      <table th:each="orderProduct : ${groupOrderCustomer.orderProducts}">
        <tr>
          <td th:text="${orderProduct.quantity} + 'st ' + ${orderProduct.name}" align="left">
            1st Kombo
          </td>
          <td th:text="${orderProduct.totalPrice}" align="right">
            100 kr
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```